# Javascript self execution function query

Tags: javascript

I was going through some github library wherein I came across the following lines:

```
//Util.js
(function(exports,global){
  global["true"] = exports;

  "use strict";
   ...rest of the code here        


})({}, function() {
    return this;
}());
```

The above file was directly included in index.html.
I am aware of the concept of self-executing functions in JS. But what purpose could the above provide ?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidchang/angular-facebook-utils/master/src/facebookUtils.js

Comment: The term `Immediate Invoked Function Expression` or `IIFE` is preferred over `self-executing` function -- as the function does not actually execute itself.

Answer (score 0):

The script is referencing the global '**this**' to hold a property called 'true' that contains an an object called 'exports' which you probably already figured out. This script appears to be one that initializes some functionality.

My guess as to WHY they are doing it this way is because they are anticipating that '**this**' might not just be run in a browser (probably for injecting mocks when unit testing for example) and so it is a way to abstract the global object.

The 'exports' and 'global' parameters are only mentioned as arguments and when setting the property global["true"] in your script. This is why I think it is an initializing script and the exports variable will be used later on by other related scripts. These related scripts which might also be under test (or whatever) and so their global object might be the same as this one.